# How did this happen to Captain America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Captain America

> lifts Mjølnir and uses lightning to attack Thanos. However, Thor's hammer doesn't have the power to bring lightning, Thor does. I mean, he is the God of Thunder, not Steve or anybody who just becomes worthy of lift the hammer!

How can this be explained?

Comment: This is also an exact copy of the original version of the question you [posted yesterday](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211495/58193) that was marked as a duplicate. Please don't repost a question, instead you can edit your original question to explain why it isn't a duplicate if you believe it not to be.

Comment: Your question contains several very important spoilers. I have edited it to add spoiler sections and make it a bit more clear. Please have a look and make sure I didn't alter the meaning.

Answer (score -2):

The hammer itself is a tool for Thor to channel his powers as god of thunder. However, the exact enchantment placed on Mjølnir is given to us in the first *Thor* film:

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.
>   <sub>Odin, *Thor*</sub>

From this, anyone judged worthy to lead Asgard is allowed to weild the hammer, and if they aren't Thor then they are permitted to use his powers while having Mjølnir in their possession.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clear duplicates.

Comment: My bad, answered before it was marked as such.